# how RUNDECK workflow works when you are using job reference

Tags: rundeck

This question is related to RUNDECK.
my RUNDECK job list is --

**Job name jobA is in Project A and it is parent job.

jobB is in project B and runs on nodeB, nodeB1.

jobc is in project C and runs on nodeC, NodeC1, NodeC2.

jobB and jobC are child jobs for jobA.**

Now jobA is my parent job which is referring to jobB and jobC in its workflow steps. Now My end goal is to run these jobs in a sequence that jobB runs first & jobC should not start untill jobB is finished.

1. can sequencing be achieved by defining jobB at first step and jobC as second step in the workflow of jobA?
2. does workflow strategy (node first, parallel, Sequential) of parent jobA have any effect on workflow steps ?
3. How can I make sure jobB runs only on its Nodes and JobC runs only on its defined nodes?
4. Does Nodes tab of Parent job have any effect on the workflow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, setting the parent job workflow Strategy to [Sequential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7uJ3.jpg).
2. Yes, that's the behavior of the referenced jobs, keep in mind that the reference jobs are steps of parent jobs.
3. Clicking the "Use referenced job's nodes" [checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fec8K.jpg).
4. Nope, but you can use an option called "Override Node Filters"? to set a specific filter for child jobs, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffaw2.jpg).

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

Comment: the option of "Use referenced job's nodes" in available in my Workflow when I try to reference a job. I am assuming a plugin is missing or not working. but not sure what to do. please help.

Comment: You need to use the latest rundeck version to use this feature. Greetings.